# How can you change the highlight color of a NSTextField within a NSTableCellView?

Tags: xcode, macos, highlight, nstextfield, nstablecellview

In storyboard when I set the Text Color of a `NSTextField` within a `NSTableCellView` to `Control Text Color` the color becomes black and when the cell is selected/highlighted it will become white. When you deselect the color will return to black. You get all this behavior for free.

I created another textfield under the default it is similar to that of iOS (see the label Game in the image below). I changed the Text Color to the gray and that all works. However, when I now select/highlight the cell, the color remains gray and does not swap to white. How can I get such behavior through Storyboard? And if not possible, through code?

[image]

Comment: Your question and tags use OS X class names, but your screenshot is showing an iOS view (e.g. `UIImageView`). What's the deal?

Comment: OSX is the deal, but I couldnt find a sample picture on Google so I used an old iOS interface image. It didn't matter because I wanted to show the text label (black) and detail text label (gray).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no automatic way to get what you want. The automatic behavior you're seeing with the black label is implemented by `NSTextFieldCell` (or one of its superclasses, like `NSCell`). It is triggered by the setting of the cell's `backgroundStyle` to `NSBackgroundStyleDark`. The cell's `backgroundStyle` is set by `NSTableCellView` when its own `backgroundStyle` is set. `NSTableCellView`'s `backgroundStyle` is set by `NSTableRowView` when its `interiorBackgroundStyle` changes, which happens when its other properties, like `selected` and `emphasized`, are set.

Anyway, the cell only automatically changes the color it uses to draw if its `textColor` is `[NSColor controlTextColor]` or has equivalent RGB values. So, it doesn't work for your gray labels.

You could implement a custom subclass of `NSTableCellView` or `NSTextField`. Your class would implement (override, for a subclass of `NSTableCellView`) `-setBackgroundStyle:`. In your method, you can check what style is being set and change the text field's `textColor`. If it's an override, call through to super. (Although `NSTextField` does not currently implement a `backgroundStyle` property, it probably will in the future. Apple has said they will be adding cover methods to controls for methods which currently only exist on cell classes. So, you should do `if ([NSTextField instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundStyle:)]) [super setBackgroundStyle:backgroundStyle];` to be future-safe.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, appreciated.